# C# - mixed assembly (C++/CLI, DirectX native) interplay (32/64bit)

Tags: interop, c++-cli, 32bit-64bit

I have a problem related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963809/anycpu-x86-x64-for-c-application-and-its-c-cli-dependency). Two players:

1. C# application
2. Mixed assembly used by 1)

The application has to support anything from Windows XP (32bit) to Windows 7 (32 & 64bit). The assembly is complicated in different ways. It contains managed C++/CLI code and some native C++ classes dancing with native DirectX. It also is linked to a few 32bit native dll's w/o source access (containing C++ classes with import libraries).

Things are working well in 32bit environments (XP and 7 tested) including the 32bit subsystem on Windows 7. Havoc happens, as soon as "Any CPU" is used on 64bit systems in order to build the complete solution. The 32bit assembly is unusable than - but seemingly only in debug mode ("cannot load, wrong format" etc.). It *seems* to work in release. A 64bit assembly build is prevented by the implicit dependencies to the mentioned 32bit third-party dll's.

Is there any way to provide a real native 64bit application able to use the assembly?

Requirement for the assembly isn't that strict. It could be both - 32 or 64bit - but as said above, should be be usable from the application one way or the other.

Comment: Removed some wrong assumption regarding p/Invoke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running into a rock hard limitation in the 64-bit version of Windows, a 64-bit process cannot execute any 32-bit machine code in-process.  You certainly have a dependency on machine code when you use C++/CLI and work with DirectX.  Although it doesn't sound like you could not execute in 64-bit mode, both C++/CLI and DirectX can be compiled/are available in 64-bit.

This then boils down to a build and deployment issue.  You *have* to build the C++/CLI project(s) in 64-bit mode and deploy *only* 64-bit components on a 64-bit operating system.  The main EXE must be built to AnyCPU.  Similarly, on a 32-bit operating system you must build and deploy only the 32-bit compiled version.  You solve the build issue by adding the x64 configuration to the solution so you build the 32-bit and 64-bit version separately.  You solve the deployment issue by creating two installers.

Since you have to support a 32-bit operating system anyway, the simple solution is to change the Target platform setting on your *EXE project* to x86.  Now everything always runs in 32-bit mode and you don't have to bother with the build and deployment headaches.  The only thing you miss out on is the larger virtual memory address space that's available in the 64-bit version.

Comment: > _The only thing you miss out on is the larger virtual memory address space that's available in the 64-bit version._

This could be a stumbling block. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: No it can't, you want to make this work on a 32-bit machine too.  If you want to exclusively target x64, not unreasonable today, then you don't have a problem.

Comment: To make myself more clear. Technically, the program has to run on 32bit too, you are right here. There are still use cases, where it could probe the (memory) limits on these systems. The answer in this case is not technical but: "Customer, please buy a decent system". This is acceptable in our case.

Comment: Well, I documented what you need to do to build and deploy both flavors.  Have you tried?

Comment: I cannot at this moment, because there are still dependencies on 32bit dll's, I'm unable to replace immediately. Not the DirectX stuff, this would be possible. So, I have to find a solution for this part first. The most valuable thing for me of your answer is, that I can do nothing to circumvent this step, but have to replace dependencies completely by 64bit variants.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the C++/CLI project for a minute.

You have third-party 32-bit DLLs.  These CANNOT load in a 64-bit process.  So your main application will have to be 32-bit.  This restriction has nothing to do with the C++/CLI middleman.

The only way you can make use of these DLLs from a 64-bit application is to load them in a separate (32-bit) process and marshal data back and forth.

Comment: It's a shame that the 32-bit loading and marshalling can't be done in-proc.

Comment: @Gabe: How would you do that?  You'd have a context switch every time thunking occurred, because 32-bit code requires 32-bit mapping in the CPU TLB, and 64-bit code requires 64-bit mappings.  It would ultimately not be much cheaper than cross-process marshalling, and would be a lot of work.  If there's already a solution that's just as good and needed for other reasons (i.e. cross-process marshalling also allows crossing security boundaries), why not use the existing method?

Comment: @Ben It boils down to this difference. As I mentioned, this is the valuable information I got from this thread. The other options are rather irrelevant to me (cf. my other question here, the 2nd under 'Linked'). So I have to make sure, I get a complete set of 64-bit Dll's.

Comment: Everytime a 32-bit process makes a system call, the CPU has to go into 64-bit mode, marshal the data, make the system call, marshal the data back, and go back to 32-bit mode to resume execution. If you could just host Wow64 in your own process, you could let it handle loading and execution of 32-bit DLLs and let P/Invoke do the marshalling.

Comment: @Gabe: No marshaling is necessary for system calls, since the kernel has direct access to the memory of all processes.

Comment: The kernel doesn't know that you're running 32-bit code, so it would get utterly confused by your 32-bit pointers and garbage in the upper half of 64-bit registers.

Comment: @Gabe: What do you mean it doesn't know you're running 32-bit code?  It has full access to the process object.  And anyway, the kernel maps user-mode pointers to physical addresses using the active process TLB, after that mapping is done all addresses are 48-bit physical addresses, completely independent of the size of the user-mode pointer.

Comment: You've never used a 64-bit debugger to debug a 32-bit process, have you? There's no such thing as a real 32-bit process; 32-bit code runs inside a 64-bit emulator called WOW64. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384274(v=VS.85).aspx: "Thunking is done in user mode... The thunks extract arguments from the 32-bit stack, extend them to 64 bits, then make the native system call."

Comment: @Gabe: That's not marshaling.  And perhaps you didn't notice, this thunking is not a general solution for any call between 32-bit and 64-bit code.  It requires the 32-bit DLL to be rewritten to call the thunks instead of performing a `syscall` or ordinary function call, and no DLL except `ntdll.dll` (x86 version) has been rewritten.  Certainly the third-party DLLs mentioned by Michael will not be written to call thunks.

Comment: Thunking is only necessary when calling between 32-bit and 64-bit code. Assuming that this were actually possible and that the 32-bit code didn't try to call back into the 64-bit code, the CLR's interop layer could handle all of the marshaling (or thunking, if you prefer) between his 64-bit code and 32-bit code. If it can interop with native DLLs and COM, why not 32-bit code?

Comment: @Gabe: "and the 32-bit code didn't try to call back into the 64-bit code".  That's a huge condition.  How many DLLs do you know of that don't try to call functions in `kernel32` or `user32`?  In a 64-bit process, those are 64-bit system libraries, which the 32-bit DLL won't be equipped to handle.  You'd have to rewrite every single function in the Windows API to perform thunking, not just the `ntdll` system calls.

Comment: I'd hope it would be clear that the 32-bit emulator would load 32-bit versions of DLLs that the 32-bit code is linked to *in addition to* all of the 64-bit DLLs that it uses.

Comment: @Gabe: Those 32-bit DLLs won't work in a 64-bit process.  All the data they need to access is 64-bit.  Or are you suggesting separate data structures, that a file handle opened by the 64-bit code can't be handed to the 32-bit DLL?  Windows created on the 64-bit side can't be seen by the 32-bit DLL, because the window procedure expects 64-bit arguments and the user data is 64-bit?  We're back into the realm of imposing so many restrictions that you might as well have a separate process.

Comment: The 32-bit emulator *already* deals with moving handles back and forth between 32-bit and 64-bit code. It *already* translates data structures back and forth. I don't see any additional requirements beyond what's required to communicate with a 64-bit kernel.

Comment: @Gabe: There are a huge number of data structures that stay in user mode, like `OVERLAPPED` and `CRITICAL_SECTION`, window message queues, etc.  None of those are translated under current WOW64, all of them would have to be under the system you propose.  "32-bit emulator"?  Are you talking about Itanium?  I'm pretty sure the focus of this question is x86_64, not Itanium.  More to the point, right now the conversion takes place at very specifically defined points.

Comment: @Gabe: Under a cross-bitness p/invoke, the translation would potentially be needed for every single argument passed.  But how would p/invoke know whether an `IntPtr` argument represents a pointer (which would require mapping the memory into the 32-bit-accessible space) or a HANDLE?  Both are the same size, but they need quite different translation schemes, and p/invoke signatures just don't have the information necessary to discriminate between them.  In cross-process work, functions like `DuplicateHandle` take care of the translation.  In-process DLLs don't call these helper functions.

Comment: `OVERLAPPED` and `CRITICAL_SECTION` can't be marshaled with P/Invoke regardless of bitness, and message queues are in the kernel. I call it an emulator because MS does (see my earlier link). On AMD64 it emulates just the 32-bit aspect of it; on Itanium it has a separate DLL to emulate the actual CPU. To P/Invoke, an `IntPtr` is entirely opaque -- if you need to pass a data structure, you need to define it as a `struct`. Wow64 translates handles by truncating or sign-extending them, so P/Invoke could do the same for any `IntPtr`.

Comment: @Gabe: You're the one who keeps using the term "marshaling".  There's no marshaling going on.  P/invoke handles `OVERLAPPED` and `CRITICAL_SECTION` just fine, by pinning the memory.  WOW64 can get away with truncating handles for one reason, and only one reason: They were all created 32-bit in the first place, and therefore they all fit in 32 bits of address space.  If you had 64-bit code creating objects and allocating memory, then passing the resulting handles and pointers to 32-bit DLLs, truncation would not work.  To make it work, you'd need to impose the 32-bit restrictions process-wide.

Comment: @Gabe: And we haven't even addressed what happens to the singleton pattern when the same process simultaneously loads 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the same DLL.