# C++/CLI equivalent of COM 'out-of-process' server

Tags: .net, com, c++-cli, interop, interprocess

Caused by my [problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500095/c-mixed-assembly-c-cli-directx-native-interplay-32-64bit) the following question occured to me:

Is it possible to produce a C++/CLI (or more general .NET) assembly without using COM wrappers as an assembly running out-of-process and able to cross bitness boundaries between 'host' and 'client' in a similar way COM+/DCOM can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is probably [.NET Framework Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I'll make the obligatory "you should use WCF" note.

Comment: Do you both have experience regarding performance of these technologies? The task includes video processing with calls into the server at frame rate frequency (25-30fps). I suspect, even video data marshaling costs are inevitable. In the worst case transfer and conversion of the complete data, something I can completely avoid with in-process techniques.